# Неправильно работает explode()

Tags: php

На сколько я понял, это только с русским такое происходит.

---

Допустим, у меня есть следующая конструкция

```
$txt=explode(" ",'т т т');
return $txt[0] == 'т';
```

и вся проблема в том, что возвращает она `false`.
В то время, как

```
echo $txt[0].$txt[1];
```

выводит `тт`;

А вот, что показывает `var_dump`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "т"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "т"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "т"
}
```

(можете сами убедиться — [пример](http://s757.mait.in.ua/dragtrans/))

если честно, то я понятия не имею, как это исправить, разве что, написать функцию-подобие `explode`, но она слишком громоздкая.

Comment: Вы не правы. Возвращает true http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/42eab3d3bfa061471bc21bea9b22541af1c26dd5

Comment: исправил вопрос, теперь не работает)

Comment: Да и теперь работает как задумывалось http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6788c8cc1809aa6c62bb6c3c1145d6a4de67aae

Comment: довольно странно... У меня не работает. А такое может зависеть от хостинга?

Comment: Версия php у вас какая?

Comment: у меня php 5.4.45

Comment: Должно нормально работать. Но рекомендую минимум 5.6 использовать, так как более ранние версии php уже не поддерживаются и устарели. Если изучаете php, то уже только php 7 и выше.

Comment: У меня на локалке 7 стоит(там тоже такая же проблема). Отличий особо не вижу, пока не "познал глубИны";

Comment: Что ж... Попробую разбить значение из массива и посмотреть, что там за лишний символ

Comment: Там нет лишнего символа. Кириллические символы в кодировке UTF-8 занимают 2 байта! Но тут `$txt[0] == 'т'` с обоих сторон сравнения у вас по 2 байта, так что должен быть `true`  в результате.

Comment: Мда... В кодировке UTF-8... Бывает

Comment: я просто забыл кодировку сменить

Comment: Если вы думаете использовать кодировку отличную от UTF-8, то зря.

Comment: Нет, нет... Я просто забыл её сменить. "Суровые реалии notepad++")